# In Native safari app extension How we can call a javascript function with argumemts from swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I just want to call a javascript function from swift file in safari app extension i tied a lot .
I am new in swift do i dont know how to do so please help me out:

```
import SafariServices
import JavaScriptCore
import WebKit
class SafariExtensionHandler: SFSafariExtensionHandler,WKNavigationDelegate {

    override func messageReceived(withName messageName: String, from page: SFSafariPage, userInfo: [String : Any]?) {
        // This method will be called when a content script provided by your extension calls safari.extension.dispatchMessage("message").

        SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow { (window) in
            window?.getActiveTab { (tab) in
                tab?.getActivePage(completionHandler: { (page1) in
                    page1?.webFrame.javaScriptContext.evaluateScript("myFunction('123')");
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error:

> [SFSafariPage webFrame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 2):

I think the way it is described in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Animalify/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017383-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) is to call a dispatchMessageToScript function in the file with your primary class aka the SafariExtensionHandler class and set up a listener on the javascript file to listen for the message that is dispatched and act on it according to the message.

So, the file with your primary class (SafariExtensionHandler.swift in my case) would look something like this.

```
import SafariServices

class SafariExtensionHandler: SFSafariExtensionHandler {

    override func messageReceived(withName messageName: String, from page: SFSafariPage, userInfo: [String : Any]?) {
        // This method will be called when a content script provided by your extension calls safari.extension.dispatchMessage("message").
        if messageName == "GetWebsiteUrl" {
            page.dispatchMessageToScript(withName: "WebsiteUrl")
        }
    }
}
```

And the javascript file you're injecting would look something like this.

```
// Wait for the DOM to load before dispatching a message to the app extension's Swift code.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    safari.extension.dispatchMessage("GetWebsiteUrl");
});

// Listens for messages sent from the app extension's Swift code.
safari.self.addEventListener("message", messageHandler);

function messageHandler(event) {
    if(event.name === "WebsiteUrl"){
        console.log("WebsiteUrl >>>", document.URL)
    }
}
```